Github Pages Not Synced and Acting Weirdly
I'm having an issue with my repository's GitHub Pages site. Specifically, it's not updating and seemingly out of sync with my repository. I know it's not even an issue with just giving it some time to update because it's been almost two hours and the site has still not updated (GitHub pages sites normally take a couple of minutes to update). In fact, I even disabled my repository's GitHub Pages site and it was still live for an hour until I gave up and put its status back to enabled. I have no idea why it's acting like this, but maybe it's because I forked my repository into another one of my repositories that is under one of my GitHub organizations and because that repository is two commits ahead? Though, I wouldn't see why that would cause the issue because in the end of the day, those repositories are independent.
Here is the repository with the GitHub Pages site not synced (the link to the site is in the README):
https://github.com/AlexMisra1/Pickleball-Club-Website-Template
Here is the forked repository under my GitHub organization:
https://github.com/Gunn-High-School-Pickleball-Club/Gunn-High-School-Pickleball-Club-Website?tab=readme-ov-file
I tried solutions that worked for other people that were having the same issues of their site not updating, like clearing my cache and waiting some time. None of those worked for me. Maybe it has to do with branches or something?
